# Inserting data into `post meta` table?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, query, wpdb

How would I be able to insert data into the post meta table? I know how querying and wpdb works but I have no idea how I can just insert it into the table.

I have these two fields I want to insert ID and Title where Title should become a new post in my Custom Post type Company and ID should be the Content of it. I unfortunately have no idea how to do this.

EDIT: I'm not sure if it HAS to be the post meta table but as long as a new Custom post type post appears.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to use the `post_meta` here, as all the Information is available in `posts`.

To insert a new post, use `wp_insert_post( $post )`, and pass the arguments to your `$post`-array. This function can return a `WP_Error`-object for Error handling (if the second argument is set to `true`, returns 0 on error if false), and returns the `ID` of the inserted post.

See the full list of arguments for `wp_insert_post()` on the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

```
$post = array(
    'post_content'   => $content, // The content you want to have set in the content
    'post_title'     => $title, // The title of your post.
    'post_status'    => 'publish', // Whatever status you want to have
    'post_type'      => 'your_custom_post_type' // the slug of your custom post type
); 

$thisid = wp_insert_post( $post, true ); // insert the post and allow WP_Error object

if ( is_wp_error( $thisid ) ) {
    // Error handling
} else {
    // the rest of your code, inserting metadata
    update_post_meta( $thisid, 'your_meta_key', $your_meta_value );
}
```

Comment: So this generates everything in the `wp_posts` table? For example the link etc? Although i'm not sure how i'm going to accomplish the following, say I have queried data from a secondary non WP database(which I have) and say i'd want that data to go into the WP DB. Would I need to add a button on the bottom of it and make an `isset` that would execute what you said? If so than this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Also one last thing `post_content` say the content is a field made with ACF how would I instead call that?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute any query as follows and check for success , Let me know if it works.

Praveen

```
$InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO post_meta VALUES (Enter Values Here)";

//Create a query named InsertQuery

$insert = $wpdb->query($InsertQuery);

//Execute InsertQuery

if($wpdb->insert_id){
    echo 'Post Entered Successfully.';
}else{
    echo 'Unable to Insert Post.';
}

//Check if the Query has run successfully
```

Comment: Yes I know this is possible but when I look at the database I notice a few things. What I want is to insert a bit of data into the columns `post_title` and `post_content`. BUT I want it to go to a `custom post type` called `Company` which means in my VALUES I also have to enter `post_type`. But what I am wondering is if it's okay to just enter those values and being able to edit them in WP_Admin without having filled in for example the column `guid` .